# Adding color bar to a table matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code for making a table plot in matplotlib.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=True, xticks = [], yticks = [])
tb = plt.table(cellText = cells[:30], rowLabels = range(30), colLabels = range(30), loc = 'center',cellColours = plt.cm.hot(normal(cells[:30])))
ax.add_table(tb)
plt.show()
```

plt is a pyplot object

I would like to add a color bar to this for the colormap I use.

I tried doing `fig.colorbar()` but that gives me a canvas error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create dummy image by `imshow` and hide it:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=True, xticks = [], yticks = [])
cells = np.random.randint(0, 100, (10, 10))
img = plt.imshow(cells, cmap="hot")
plt.colorbar()
img.set_visible(False)
tb = plt.table(cellText = cells, 
    rowLabels = range(10), 
    colLabels = range(10), 
    loc = 'center',
    cellColours = img.to_rgba(cells))
ax.add_table(tb)
plt.show()
```

[image]